# Writing raw bits to a file in Lazarus

Tags: data-conversion, freepascal, lazarus

Let's suppose I generate a string of randomly ordered 1's and 0's.
If I write said string to a file, it will be written as an ANSI string, which is not what I want to do. I want to instead write the 1's and 0's in the string as raw bits. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the input string, character by character, and replace every '0' by a #0, and every '1' by a #1.

```
const
  txt = '0001010001011110101110101010000001011111';
var
  s: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(s, Length(txt));
  for i:=1 to Length(txt) do
    if txt[i] = '0' then
      s[i] := #0
    else if txt[i] = '1' then
      s[i] := #1
    else
    begin
      WriteLn('Unsupported character in input string');
      Halt;
    end;

  //... write to file here (you should know how to do it) ...
end;
```

Or you could subtract the ordinal value of the character '0' from each character and cast the result back to char. The result will be #0 for '0' or #1 for '1'.

```
SetLength(s, Length(txt));
for i := 1 to Length(txt) do
  s[i] := char(ord(txt[i]) - ord('0'));
```